# Wordpress не создаёт миниатюры изображений

Tags: php, wordpress

Создаю собственную тему wordpress с нуля, вернее на шаблоне с https://underscores.me/
Столкнулся с проблемой, Wordpress не создаёт миниатюры для изображений при загрузки их в медиа-библиотеку. То есть я загружаю изображение, открываю папку uploads (на своем локальном хостинге xampp), и там только одна версия изображения.
Поддержка миниатюр включена

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Пробовал настраивать собственные размеры миниатюр

```
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-small', 320, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium', 425, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium_large', 768, 9999, false );
add_image_size( 'dommilosti-large', 1024, 9999, false );
```

В том числе и через хук

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'true_add_image_size' );
function true_add_image_size() {
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-small', 320, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium', 425, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-medium_large', 768, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'dommilosti-large', 1024, 9999, false );
}
```

Указывал размеры для миниатюр в настройки > медиа-файлы, убирал. Размеры регистрируются, но wp тем не менее никак загруженные изображения по ним не обрабатывает. При загрузке новых изображений только одна копия, никаких новых миниатюр не создаётся. Кто-нибудь подскажет куда хоть копать? Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Для создания миниатюр, нужно подключить расширение для php. В файле php.ini, раскомментируйте строку

`extension=gd2`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, добавил данную строку в файл php.ini, но, к сожалению, проблема пока осталась

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать для какого типа материалов поддержка

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению это не сработало

Answer (score 0):

При создании нового размера миниатюр, все уже существующие изображения не регенерируются под этот новый размер. Если у вас проблема со старыми (уже загруженными изображениями), то надо их перегенерировать после создания нового размера миниатюр. Для этого подойдет плагин типа "Regenerate Thumbnails" или его аналоги. Надо запустить процес регенерации и плагин обработает все уже загруженные изображения, пересоздав под них миниатюры всех размеров.

По идее, новые изображения должны уже автоматически генерироваться во всех размерах.